# Is it possible to do lossless compression using Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, lossless-compression

I am running a cityscape and nature photography website that contains a lot of images which range from 50kb-2mb in size.  I have already shrunk them down in size using a batch photo editor so I can't lose any more quality in the images without them getting too grainy.

Google page insights recommends lossless compression and I am trying to figure out how to solve this.  These specific images are in s3 buckets and being served by AWS cloudfront

Losslessly compressing https://d339oe4gm47j4m.cloudfront.net/bw107.jpg could save 57.6KiB (38% reduction).
Losslessly compressing https://luminoto-misc.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bob_horsch.jpg could save 40.6KiB (42% reduction). ...... and a hundred more of the same.

Can Cloudfront do the compression before the image is server to the client?  Or do I have to do some other type of compression and then reupload each file to a new s3 bucket.  I am looking for a solution where cloudfront will do it.

I have searched around but haven't found a definitive answer.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 3):

### Update

As implicitly [pointed out by Ryan Parman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24471463/45773) (+1), there are two different layers at play when it comes to compression (and/or optimization), which seem to get mixed a bit in this discussion so far:

My initial answer below has addressed *lossless compression using Cloudfront* as per your question title, which is concerned with the [HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) layer:

> **HTTP compression** is a capability that can be built into [web servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) and [web clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_client) to make better use of available bandwidth, and provide greater transmission speeds between both.
>
> [...] data is [compressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) before it is sent from the server: compliant browsers will announce what methods are supported to the server before downloading the correct format; browsers that do not support compliant compression method will download uncompressed data. [...]

That is, the compress/decompress operation is usually automatically handled by the server and the client to optimize bandwidth usage and transmission performance - the difference with CloudFront is, that its server implementation does indeed *not handle compression automatically* like most web servers, which is why you need to prepare a compressed representation yourself if desired.

- This kind of compression works best with text files like HTML, CSS and JavaScript etc., but isn't useful (or even detrimental) with binary data formats that are already compressed by themselves like ZIP and other prepacked archives and esp. image formats like PNG and JPEG.

Now, your question body talks about a different compression/optimization layer all together, namely lossy [JPEG_compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_compression) and specifically [Lossless_editing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Lossless_editing) as well as optimization via [jpegoptim](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim) - this has nothing to do with how files are handled by HTTP servers and clients, rather just compressing/optimizing the files themselves to better match the performance constraints within specific use cases like web or mobile browsing, where the transmission of a digital photo in its original size wouldn't make any sense when it is simply to be viewed on a web page for example.

- This kind of compression/optimization is one that is rarely offered by web servers themselves so far, even though notable efforts like Google's [mod_pagespeed](http://www.modpagespeed.com/) are available these days - usually it is the responsibility of the web designer to prepare appropriate assets, ideally optimized for and selectively delivered to the expected target audience via [CSS Media queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries).

---

### Initial Answer

[AWS CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is capable of [Serving Compressed Files](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html), however, this is to be taken literally:

> Amazon CloudFront can serve both compressed and uncompressed files
>   from an origin server. **CloudFront relies on the origin server either
>   to compress the files or to have compressed and uncompressed versions
>   of files available; CloudFront does not perform the compression on
>   behalf of the origin server**. With some qualifications, CloudFront can
>   also serve compressed content from Amazon S3. For more information,
>   see [Choosing the File Types to Compress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#ChoosingFilesToCompress). *[emphasis mine]*

That is, you'll need to provide compressed versions yourself, but once you've set this up, this is transparent for clients - please note that the *content must be compressed using gzip; other compression algorithms are not supported*:

> [...] If the request header includes additional content encodings, for example, deflate or sdch, CloudFront removes them before forwarding the request to the origin server. If gzip is missing from the Accept-Encoding field, CloudFront serves only the uncompressed version of the file. [...]

Details regarding the requirements and process are outlined in [How CloudFront Serves Compressed Content from a Custom Origin](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#CompressedCustomOrigin) and [Serving Compressed Files from Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#CompressedS3).

Comment: thanks for the comments.  I had read those articles and didnt see that 'other compression algo are not supported'  So then it seems that an optimzing program like jpegoptim would have no effect if the images were served from cloudfront because they only support gzip, right? [http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/workflow/jpegoptim-optipng-intro/]

Comment: @jeff_horsch - I've updated my answer with an attempt to clarify the two different compression/optimization layers and techniques at play here.

Comment: Nowadays, CloudFront can [compress for you text contents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html). Unfortunately, it does not seem it can optimize images, yet.

Answer (score 2):

JPEGOptim doesn't do any *compression* -- it does *optimization*.

The short answer is, **yes**, you should always use JPEGOptim on your `.jpg` files to *optimize* them before uploading them to S3 (or whatever your source storage is). This has been a good idea since forever.

If you're talking about files which are plain text-based (e.g., CSS, JavaScript, HTML), then gzip-compression is the appropriate solution, and **Steffen Opel** would have had the 100% correct answer.

Comment: Also: Google owns the source code and specification for a competing image format called WebP, which is more efficient and better optimized than classic JPEG. Google's tools will often recommend the use of WebP over JPEG. https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/jpg-vs-webp

Answer (score 0):

The only compression amazon really supports is zip or gzip. You are able to load those compressions into S3, and then do things like loads directly into resources like Redshift. So in short, no amazon does not provide you with the service you are looking for. This would be something you would have to leverage yourself...

Comment: thanks for that response.  please see my comment above